# How to call paramterized function from arrow flight rpc server/client code?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pyarrow, apache-arrow

This is an example arrow flight RPC server that I have created:

```
database_url = f'postgresql://postgres:{passwd}@{host}:5432/local_db'
conn = adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi.connect(database_url)

class NumberFlightServer(flight.FlightServerBase):
    def do_get(self, context, ticket):
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT id, traces from drives")
            data = cur.fetch_arrow_table()
        return flight.RecordBatchStream(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    location = flight.Location.for_grpc_tcp("localhost", 50051)
    server = NumberFlightServer(location)
    print("Starting the server on localhost:50051")
    server.serve()
```

And this is the client code:

```
async def main():
    loc = flight.Location.for_grpc_tcp("localhost", 50051)
    client = flight.FlightClient(loc).do_get(flight.Ticket(b''))
    reader = client.read_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Now I want to integrate multiple python functions similar to below which accepts a bunch of parameters and queries a postgres database using sqlalchemy for instance. I didn't find any example which explains how to do it. Is it possible to do it with Arrow Flight RPC mechanism.

```
async def get_drives(id: str, mb_box: str, session: Session):
    query = session.query(Drives)
    if id:
        query = query.filter(Drives.id == id).first()
        return query
    if mb_box:
        query = query.filter(Drives.box == mb_box).all()
        return query
    return query.all()
```

Comment: Wouldn't Flight SQL be the logical choice?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/FlightSql.html https://blog.djnavarro.net/posts/2022-10-18_arrow-flight/#a-python-example https://voltrondata.com/resources/running-arrow-flight-server-querying-data-jdbc-adbc